# Python search all of List1 and match against List2[s]

Tags: python

I'm working on a script that compares two lists and outputs if one or more are missing a term from `list1`. The end goal is to search all of `list1` against `list2[0]`, then `list2[1]` etc. If there is no match, append to a new list to be printed out later.

`list1` is the search, multiple values and static
`list2` is the values to search against, could be 1 to 50 values depending on input I'm grabbing from a file that I have parsed.

```
list1 = ["color:", "size:", "tip:"]
list2 = ["color:red", "color:purple", "black", "size:2", "tip:small", "tip:large", "size:4", "2", "color:blue"]
```

Here we see black and 2 are missing a parameter from `list1`. The idea would be `["black", "2"]` are appended to a new variable to be called on later as "missing parameter". If items from `list1` do not exist, the search the user is doing via `list2` will not work.

```
search_file = os.getcwd()+'/var/log/mysearch.csv'
searching = csv.reader(open(search_file, 'rt'), delimiter = ',')

list1 = ["color:", "size:", "tip:"]

for row in searching:
                search_query = urllib.parse.unquote(row[4]) #pulls row 4 from csv where search is. User enters the matching row number via command line to run a check. 
                if args.search_query == row[0]: # url decodes the search[4] based on row with id

                        newlist = []
                        #removed = (shlex.split(r)) #search might contain double quotes, split to list by spaces this would be my list2. An attempt to tokenize. 
                        # For ease of this post, I pasted the returned value from the search_file below that was converted with this command.

                        removed = ["color:red", "color:purple", "black", "size:2", "tip:small", "tip:large", "size:4", "2", "color:blue"] 

                        if all(missing) not in removed:
                                newlist.append(removed) #append to new list
                        print(newlist)
```

This would work if I was looking to find if there are any non-match between the two, I understand why it's doing it via the `all()` method but I'm not able to find a good alternative to the approach. Everything I have tried always returns the full list because it finds one item that doesn't match.

If I try doing a while loop against removed[s] and up the count, I will get "requires string as left operand, not bool"

Still new to Python so appreciate the knowledge sharing. Thanks!

Comment: ``all(list1)`` just checks whether ``list1`` contains only truthy elements (e.g. any non-empty string). Did you mean something like ``all(any(part in elem for part in list1) for elem in list2)`` perhaps?

Comment: Is it possible to have invalid headers, e.g. ``foobar:4`` where ``foobar:`` is not in ``list1``? Are there multi-header elements, e.g. ``foobar:size:3``?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
missing = [item for item in list2 if f"{item.split(':')[0]}:" not in list1]
print(missing)
```

**Output:**

```
['black', '2']
```